# VLookup with hyperlinked values - GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have two google sheets. the first sheet shows people and hours worked
the second sheet shows people and projects worked.

I want to pull in the projects from sheet two into sheet one so that I have people, projects, hours worked in one sheet.

Sheet one is something like below

| Person | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | 12 |
| Jen | 5 |
| James | 6.2 |
| Sue | 4 |

Sheet two is something like below

| Id | Person | Project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | James | Something |
| 569 | Jen | abc |
| 25 | Sue | Test |
| 456 | Sam | best_Wing |

The result I am looking for is

| Person | project | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jen | abc | 5 |
| Sam | Best_wing | 12 |
| James | Something | 6.5 |
| Sue | Test | 4 |

The names in the Person column on sheet 1 are hyperlinked. So the name is displayed in the Person Column, but when clicked on links to a different page.

I was trying to do a VLOOKUP, but I keep getting a formula parse error, I used the `=TO_TEXT(A3:A)` to pull the text from the hyperlinked field and use that as a Filter for the second sheet, but I am doing something wrong, somewhere.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A3:A), FILTER({sheet2!$B$2:B, sheet2!$C$2:C}, sheet2!$C$2:C), 3, 0)))`

Comment: Try `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, FILTER(sheet2!$B$2:C, sheet2!$C$2:C), 2, 0)))`

Comment: The only crucial thing is that you need `2` instead of `3`.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet